# Extending supercsv cell processor implementation generate warning

Tags: java, generics, supercsv

Extending some Super CSV cell processor generates `unchecked` warning.

For example:

```
package test;

import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.FmtNumber;

public class CustomFmtNumber extends FmtNumber {
    public CustomFmtNumber(String formatter) {
        super(formatter);
    }
}
```

When compiled with `-Xlint:unchecked` produces following warning:

```
CustomFmtNumber.java:5: warning: [unchecked] execute(Object,CsvContext) in FmtNumber implements <T>execute(Object,CsvContext) in CellProcessor
public class CustomFmtNumber extends FmtNumber {
       ^
  return type requires unchecked conversion from Object to T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>execute(Object,CsvContext)
1 warning
```

`CellProcessor` defines `execute` as follows:

```
<T> T execute(final Object value, final CsvContext context);
```

`FmtNumber` has indeed non-generic implementation of execute, like many other implementations. Why is it so?

Question is for Super CSV developers -- why use generic types in interface, when its not used, maybe create a non-generic interface beside `CellProcessor` ? Is this something you can target for your next release?

Comment: See https://github.com/super-csv/super-csv/commit/5841601ec672be7556b42d02210fbaa19a5f5b79 (it was done on purpose)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, maybe github would be even better place to get answer for this as well.

Comment: Opened issue in github: https://github.com/super-csv/super-csv/issues/119